# Highlighting a Group of Divs on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a group of DIVs that are in a list and I want to hightlight the group based on where a user clicks. Here is an example of what I mean.

```
<div id="messageBubbleArea">

    <div class="fromThem msgBubble">
        <span class="msgName">+12125551212</span><br>
           ￼Happy There!<br>
        <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2014</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div> 

    <div class="fromThem msgBubble">
        <span class="msgName">+12015553434</span><br>
        Hope you all are having a fun day!<br>
        <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2014</span>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

</div>
```

The idea here is that I should be able to select a message bubble which will be flagged as a starting point and then select a second message bubble which will be flagged as an ending point, and then highlight all the div's between the two points.

There is a challenges here. Each message bubble is either floating right or floating left so just adding a highlight to the divs would not work as it would not stretch all the way across the main "messageBubbleArea" container.

So. that being the case, how would I highlight a selection of "msgBubble" div's to show a bunch of selected conversation bubbles? I thought of setting a start and an end and then when the end is selected adding a parent div to those specific bubbles which would have a highlight set on them but it seems very cumbersome and I am not sure it is the right way to go about it. Does anybody have any other recommendations?

Here is the JS so far:

```
 $('#messageBubbleArea').on('click', '.msgBubble', function(){

        if($('#messageBubbleArea').find('.startHere').length == 0){
            $(this).addClass('startHere');
        }
        else{
            if(!$(this).hasClass('startHere')){
                $(this).addClass('endHere');
            }
        }
    });
```

EDIT: Here is a JsFiddle.....https://jsfiddle.net/30nLueae/

Thanks!

Comment: a small fiddle with the styles included may help in understanding the question a _little_ bit more. :)

Comment: So I started to build it out but it doesnt seem to work with the js stuff.
https://jsfiddle.net/30nLueae/

Comment: yes nextUntil() prevUntil() will be very handy in your case

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: Just found a solution with better readability.

I think I solve it, check the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/30nLueae/7/).. Keep in mind, that it's possible that `startHere` might be under `endHere`. Since you didn't mention that, then I assume you missed that case.

```js
var start = 0;
$('#messageBubbleArea').on('click', '.msgBubble', function() {
  if ($('#messageBubbleArea').find('.startHere').length == 0) {
    $(this).addClass('startHere');
    $(this).css('background-color', 'gray');
    start = parseInt($(this).attr('messageid'), 10);
  } else {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('startHere')) {
      $(this).addClass('endHere');
      var cur = $(this);
      while(!cur.hasClass('startHere')){
        cur.css('background-color', 'gray');

        //if endHere is below startHere, change cur to previous .msgBubble div
       if( parseInt(cur.attr('messageid'), 10) > start){
            cur = cur.prev().prev();
        }else{
            cur = cur.next().next();
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. Yea, I thought about the order of end being before, I have that handled. The only thing I would comment on this is that I was trying to get the entire row highlighted, not just the chat bubble.

I would also consider using nextUntil() instead of the while loop for applying the css.

Answer (score 0):

Just check this one whether it is going with your requirement or not.

[Here is the js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/7Lm3tg6x/2/)

If you want start node blue, end node green and selected nodes as yellow then this is your javascript

```
var started = false;
var startEl;
$('.msgBubble').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).hasClass('startHere')) {
            started = false;
          startEl = null;
            $(this).removeClass('startHere');
        } else {
            if (started) {
                    $(this).parent().find('.msgBubble').removeClass('endHere selectHere');
                var endEl = this;
                var els = $(this).parent().find('.msgBubble');
                startIndex = els.index(startEl);
                endIndex = els.index(endEl);
                $(this).addClass('endHere');
                if (startIndex > endIndex) {
                    for (var i = endIndex + 1; i < startIndex; i++) {
                        $(els[i]).addClass('selectHere');
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
                        $(els[i]).addClass('selectHere');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('startHere');
                startEl = this;
                started = true;
            }
        }
});
$('#messageBubbleArea').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.msgBubble').removeClass('startHere endHere selectHere');
  started = false;
  startEl = null;
});
```

If you want all the selected nodes in same color

```
var started = false;
var startEl;
$('.msgBubble').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).hasClass('startHere')) {
            $(this).removeClass('startHere');
            started = false;
            startEl = null;
        } else {
            if (started) {
                    $(this).parent().find('.msgBubble').removeClass('endHere selectHere');
                var endEl = this;
                var els = $(this).parent().find('.msgBubble');
                startIndex = els.index(startEl);
                endIndex = els.index(endEl);
                $(this).addClass('endHere');
                $(startEl).addClass('endHere');
                if (startIndex > endIndex) {
                    for (var i = endIndex + 1; i < startIndex; i++) {
                        $(els[i]).addClass('endHere');
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
                        $(els[i]).addClass('endHere');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('startHere');
                startEl = this;
                started = true;
            }
        }
});
$('#messageBubbleArea').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.msgBubble').removeClass('startHere endHere selectHere');
  started = false;
  startEl = null;
});
```

```js
var started = false;
var startEl;
$('.msgBubble').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).hasClass('startHere')) {
            $(this).removeClass('startHere');
            started = false;
            startEl = null;
        } else {
            if (started) {
                    $(this).parent().find('.msgBubble').removeClass('endHere selectHere');
                var endEl = this;
                var els = $(this).parent().find('.msgBubble');
                startIndex = els.index(startEl);
                endIndex = els.index(endEl);
                $(this).addClass('endHere');
                $(startEl).addClass('endHere');
                if (startIndex > endIndex) {
                    for (var i = endIndex + 1; i < startIndex; i++) {
                        $(els[i]).addClass('endHere');
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
                        $(els[i]).addClass('endHere');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('startHere');
                startEl = this;
                started = true;
            }
        }
});
$('#messageBubbleArea').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('.msgBubble').removeClass('startHere endHere selectHere');
  started = false;
  startEl = null;
});
```

```css
#messageBubbleArea {
    font: 14px Arial;
    margin-top: 104px;
    max-height: 694px;
    min-height: 694px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 99%;
}

.fromThem::before {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #e5e5ea;
    border-left: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
}

.fromThem {
    background-color: #e5e5ea;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    margin-right: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fromThem, .fromMe {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    position: relative;
}

#messageBubbleArea {
    font: 14px Arial;
}

.msgName {
    font-size: 9px;
}

.msgDate {
    font-size: 9px;
}
.startHere {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
.startHere::before {
  border-bottom-color: #1e90ff;
}
.endHere {
  background-color: #40ffd5;
}
.endHere::before {
  border-bottom-color: #40ffd5;
}
.selectHere {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.selectHere::before {
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messageBubbleArea">
  <div deliveredstamp="1397995207" messageid="782" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">+15515875678</span><br>
    Happy Hoppy Easter!<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398020299" messageid="783" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">+13475319684</span><br>
    Hope you all are having a fun day!<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

```js
var started = false;
var startEl;
$('.msgBubble').on('click', function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
        if ($(this).hasClass('startHere')) {
            $(this).removeClass('startHere');
            started = false;
            startEl = null;
        } else {
            if (started) {
              $(this).parent().find('.msgBubble').removeClass('endHere selectHere');
                var endEl = this;
                var els = $(this).parent().find('.msgBubble');
                startIndex = els.index(startEl);
                endIndex = els.index(endEl);
                $(this).addClass('endHere');
                if (startIndex > endIndex) {
                    for (var i = endIndex + 1; i < startIndex; i++) {
                        $(els[i]).addClass('selectHere');
                    }
                } else {
                    for (var i = startIndex + 1; i < endIndex; i++) {
                        $(els[i]).addClass('selectHere');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('startHere');
                startEl = this;
                started = true;
            }
        }
});
$('#messageBubbleArea').on('click', function() {
 $(this).find('.msgBubble').removeClass('startHere endHere selectHere');
  started = false;
  startEl = null;
});
```

```css
#messageBubbleArea {
    font: 14px Arial;
    margin-top: 104px;
    max-height: 694px;
    min-height: 694px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 99%;
}

.fromThem::before {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #e5e5ea;
    border-left: 9px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
}

.fromThem {
    background-color: #e5e5ea;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    margin-right: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.fromThem, .fromMe {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
    max-width: 80%;
    padding: 5px 9px;
    position: relative;
}

#messageBubbleArea {
    font: 14px Arial;
}

.msgName {
    font-size: 9px;
}

.msgDate {
    font-size: 9px;
}
.startHere {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
.startHere::before {
  border-bottom-color: #1e90ff;
}
.endHere {
  background-color: #40ffd5;
}
.endHere::before {
  border-bottom-color: #40ffd5;
}
.selectHere {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.selectHere::before {
  border-bottom-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messageBubbleArea">
  <div deliveredstamp="1397995207" messageid="782" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">+15515875678</span><br>
    Happy Hoppy Easter!<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398020299" messageid="783" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">+13475319684</span><br>
    Hope you all are having a fun day!<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div deliveredstamp="1398029166" messageid="784" class="fromThem msgBubble">
    <span class="msgName">Mom </span><br>
    Happy Easter<br>
    <span class="msgDate">Jan 1, 2001</span>
  </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In the fiddle it doesnt seem to be working though.

Comment: @ackerchez You can check now. I forgot to include jquery. Please tell me if you need anything which I missed.

Comment: thanks for sending this over. Any idea how to make the entire row highlighted?

Comment: In what condition you want to select the row?